# Registering PostUpdateEventListener for Hibernate within JBPM without rebuilding JBPM

Tags: java, hibernate, jbpm, kie

I have a JBPM 7.44/PAM 7.9 application where I listen for Task-related events (using a TaskLifeCycleEventListener) but also need a PostUpdateEventListener to listen for Hibernate update events.  How can I hook the PostUpdateEventListener into Hibernate without rebuilding JBPM?  I have not modified the JBPM source code (so do not affect the source code) and am a Spring novice (so would like to avoid extensive configuration within the war file).

Here is the class with the PostUpdateEventListener:

```
public class UserTaskIdUpdateListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserTaskIdUpdateListener.class);

    public static final UserTaskIdUpdateListener INSTANCE = new UserTaskIdUpdateListener();

    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
           final Object entity = event.getEntity();
           final String cName = entity.getClass().getName();
           
           LOGGER.info("Intercepted Hibernate update for " + cName);
           
           if("com.mycompany.MyUserTask".equals(cName)) {
             // Since they are structurally the same, try to coerce
             MyUserTaskInJava candidateTask = (MyUserTaskInJava ) entity;
             if (candidateTask.getId() != null) {
                 LOGGER.info("found id on the MyUserTaskInJava - next put in a list the WIH can access");
             }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by putting the listener in its own archive (JAR) and under the kie-server.war/WEB-INF/lib directory.  The server can be restarted, or kie-server disabled/re-enabled or kie-server redeployed to have the listener picked up.